# How to enable ldap in php MAMP?

Tags: php, ldap

I would like to create a Login System with Active Directory.
so I use the adLDAP to do that.
but finally, When I login in web Login page, It display

```
exception 'adLDAPException' with message 'No LDAP support for PHP.
See: http://www.php.net/ldap' in C:\MAMP\htdocs\adLDAP\src\adLDAP.php:600 
Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\adLDAP\examples\authenticate.php(29): 
adLDAP->__construct() #1 {main}
```

Error

and extension php_ldap.dll in php.ini

[image]

and make sure I have php_ldap.dll file
[image]

but still not work

I create a

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

to check Is the ldap enable?? but it is not enabled......
any Idea, thx very much
My php version is MAMP PHP Version 5.6.30

Comment: however, this question helped me getting to the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To check if LDAP is available for you just check if function `ldap_connect` exists:

```
if (!function_exists('ldap_connect')) {
    die('Your server does not support LDAP');
}
```

Comment: «how to enable» is not equal to «check if it is enabled»!